# why kernel descriptors are organised in such a way?

Tags: linux-kernel

[image]

I just started to read some kernel code, the way how the descriptors are organised confuses me a lot. For instance, the trap gate descriptor, why kernel separates the offset into two and put them separately? Why can't we just organise the descriptor like this:

```
63                        32 31                      16 15                    0
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| offset [31:0]             |     selector             |    others            |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Note that it isn't about the linux kernel, the hardware(x86) is designed that way - an operating system have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

### Q. Why is the **Interrupt Descriptor** structured as follows

```
struct IDTDescr{
   uint16_t offset_1;   // offset bits 0..15
   uint16_t selector;   // a code segment selector in GDT or LDT
   uint8_t zero;        // unused, set to 0
   uint8_t type_attr;   // type and attributes, see below
   uint16_t offset_2;   // offset bits 16..31
};
```

( with the offsets split into 2 separate 16bit entries? )

> Ans. Because the `x86` architecture defines the layout that way.

---

#### Q. Why does `x86` define the layout to store a 32bit offset as two 16bit entries?

> Ans. **Most likely due to the legacy layout being carried forward from the original 8086**.

In the 8086 processor, the IDT resides at a fixed location in memory from address 0x0000 to 0x03ff, and consists of 256 instances of **32bit real-mode pointers**.

A real-mode pointer is defined as

- a 16-bit segment address and
- a 16-bit offset into that segment.

...which could be simply represented as:

```
struct 8086IDTDescr{
   uint16_t offset_1;   // offset bits 0..15
   uint16_t selector;   // a code segment selector in GDT or LDT
};
```

Subsequently the **offset was increased to 32bits (from 16bits)** and additional type-attributes were defined to differentiate between the interrupts, traps and tasks. The newly defined entries were now assigned higher bits in the newly expanded structure.

[image: Interrupts, Traps and Tasks]

The **segment selector** and **lower offset** bits continue to occupy their position as before.

---

#### Q. Why would Intel prefer to extend upon a legacy structure?

> Couple of reasons:
>
> 1. Re-use the existing HW design logic to deal with the original lower 32bits also in their newer chips.
> 2. Programmers and existing software are already familiar with the `selector` field. It makes sense not to move it around. Existing software could probably continue to use 16bit offsets by setting the `type_attr` field properly.

---

For more details checkout this detailed description of the [Interrupt Descriptor Table](http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table).